# Delete double IDs from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `PHP 7.1.33`.

I am the following array:

```
[6114, 6128, 26.89] // --> [ID_1, ID_2, similarity_value]
```

I would like to filter if `ID_1` and `ID_2` are similar and pick the array with the higher `similarity value` (if its the same value keep the first array), such as:

```
[6114, 6128, 26.89] // keep this value
[6128, 6114, 25.60]
```

I am struggeling with the comparing part of the IDs. I tried the following:

```
<?php

$valueArr = [
    [6114, 6128, 26.89],
    [6128, 6114, 25.60],
    [1000, 2000, 35.33],
    [2000, 1000, 55.55],
    [6000, 6001, 35.98],
    [6005, 6004, 200],
    [6004, 6005, 200]
];

/**
 * @param array $valueArr
 * @return array
 */
function removeDoublesAndKeepHigh($valueArr)
{
    $resArr = array();

    foreach ($valueArr as $v) {
        foreach ($valueArr as $y) {
            if ($v[0] === $y[1]) {
                if ($y[1] === $v[1]) {
                    array_push($resArr, $v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $resArr;
}

$resArr = removeDoublesAndKeepHigh($valueArr);

print_r($resArr);

/*
Wanted Result:
$resArr = [[6114, 6128, 26.89], [2000, 1000, 55.55], [6000, 6001, 35.98]];
*/
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? Should I add another `for-loop`?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: "if its the same value keep the first array" - then `6005, 6004, 200` should be in result too.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. How does the "similarity" value" correlate to the two ID values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version with taking "if its the same value keep the first array" into consideration (fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/U7H7p)) is:

```
$valueArr = [
    [6114, 6128, 26.89], 
    [6128, 6114, 25.60], 
    [1000, 2000, 35.33], 
    [2000, 1000, 55.55], 
    [6000, 6001, 35.98], 
    [6005, 6004, 200], 
    [6004, 6005, 200]
];

$newData = [];
foreach ($valueArr as $value) {
    $key = $value[0] < $value[1] 
        ? $value[0] . '-' . $value[1] 
        : $value[1] . '-' . $value[0]; 
    if (empty($newData[$key]) || $newData[$key][2] < $value[2]) {
        $newData[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($newData));
```